# Reusing IdentityServer3 refresh tokens in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I am currently working on an implementation of IdentityServer4.
The client I am doing the work for, currently runs IdentityServer3 and has alot of valid refresh tokens stored in their Tokens table.
I possible, they would like to be able to reuse these refresh tokens in the new IdentityServer4 implementation, so that the upgrade will be a seamingless experience for their customers (i.e. they don't need to log in again).

Doing some testing on the subjects, I have noticed that the hashed keys are encoded differently in IdentityServer4's PersistedGrants table than it was in IdentityServer3's Tokens table, so simply copying the tokens into the new database, doesn't work.

Are there any backwards compatibility with old IdentityServer3 refresh tokens in place for IdentityServer4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Migrating to IdentityServer4 is going to require everyone to login all over again. Even if the refresh tokens were backwards-compatible or could somehow be migrated, there are a lot of other places (for example, the revised Data Protection APIs, various cookie content) where a new ASP.NET Core ID4 server won't be able to smoothly take over from an existing ID3 implementation.

Also, be aware that both the IdentityServer4 QuickstartUI and EF persistence implementations are *not* intended to be treated as production-ready code. As of ID4 both of those concerns are officially considered your responsibility and those repos are meant as sample/reference code only. (The same is true of the ASP.NET Core EF Identity template, although Microsoft is less up-front about this.)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply :). Can you maybe expand on, or point me to a reference saying, why exactly their persistence implementation should not be used for production?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't save links when I read those comments (I _knew_ I should have!) ... it comes from various github issue comments in the ID4 and ASP.NET repositories. To make matters worse, way back in 2016 when ID4 was announced in a blog post, they specifically said refresh tokens would be compatible.

Comment: Alright, I'll continue to do some research on it :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jonasgj , may be i'm writting a little bit late but did you find something regarding this ?